# Writetourl does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have tried for a week to get writeToUrl to work, but no... nothing.
I simply want to update a file on my server from an iPhone app.
This is the code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://user:pw@192.168.120.167/test.txt"];
NSString *teststring = @"it works";

if ([teststring writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Status" message: @"Yessss" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];    
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Status" message: @"Noooooo" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];    
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

Comment: for a start you can pass error parameter to the writeToURL: method and check what error you get...

Comment: I already tried and the result is (null)...

Comment: sorry thats the real error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 518.)" UserInfo=0x6e72b30 {NSURL=http://user:pw@192.168.120.167/test.txt}

Comment: I also tried to replace the "http" with "ftp" but i got the same error message... perhaps the problem is on server side? Its a ubuntu server...

Answer (score 1):

I switched from writeToURL to writeToFile, using the exact same file path, and it suddenly worked. Seems like there might be a bug in writeToURL. This was tested on iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can only write to local files. See [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Since at present only file:// URLs are supported, there is no difference between this method and writeToFile:options:error:, except for the type of the first argument.